# Node.js throwing cannot GET / with express

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am starting to learn node.js and I am using express.

My project structure is :

```
---CardDemo
-----view
-------index.html
-----server
-------controller
---------indexController.js
-------app.js
```

Now the codes :

indexController.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = require('../server/app');

app.get('/', function(req, resp){
    resp.sendFile('../view/index.html');
});
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var port = 8000;


app.listen(port, function(error, response){
    if (error){
        console.log("Failed to run server!");
    }
});


module.exports = app;
```

When I am doing `localhost:8000/` I am getting :

```
Cannot GET /
```

What is going wrong ?

Comment: I guess the issue is root of the application and you are not accessing your root that may be have to `/CardDemo`. You have not set the path in the express. better to go to express js site and see the minimal demo at http://expressjs.com/en/guide/migrating-4.html

Comment: Get the same error : cannot get /CardDemo

Comment: Have you run the app.js file at console?

Comment: yes. Using nodemon for that.

Comment: The path you're giving for the file looks wrong. You're telling it to look for a views folder that's inside the server folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is how & what you run as a startup file.

Try running (for existing files, sourcecode and folder structure):

`node server/controller/indexController.js` (because you are exporting app not indexController)

Then try http://localhost:8000/

---

**Recommended**

Project structure :

```
|-- CardDemo
|   |-- controllers
|   |   `-- userController.js
|   |-- models
|   |   `-- userSchemaModel.js
|   |-- routes
|   |   `-- index.js
|   `-- views
|       `-- index.html
|-- config
|   `-- AppConfig.js
|-- lib
|   `-- customLib.js
|-- vendor (or public)
|    |-- javascripts
|    |   |-- jquery.js 
|    `-- stylesheets
|        `-- StyleSheet.css
|-- app.js (startup)
`-- helpers
    `-- userHelper.js
```

routes/index.js:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.json({ "Test": "Ok" });
    });
    app.get('/view', function (req, res) {
        res.render('index');
    });
    //Other routes here...
}
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express(); 

// view engine
app.set('views', 'path/views'));  
// Set static/public folder 
app.use('/static', express.static('public'));
/* 
you can also use `path.join(__dirname, 'folderName')` as standard reference to __dirname globals 
e.g. 
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
*/

require('./routes')(app);
var port = 8000;
app.listen(port, function(error, response){
    if (error){
        console.log("Failed to run server!");
    }
});
module.exports = app;
```

Now you can run command `node app.js` & try http://localhost:8000/

Comment: So how do I make it load the index.html file on localhost:8000 ? and how to render the .css and .js files included in the index.html ?

Comment: @Priyabrata: I have tried to explain some basic folder structure. But what you asked is a different altogether, you need to understand how express static/public folder(s) are set. Adding this also in code. :)

Comment: Refer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809384/whats-the-significance-of-helpers-folder-in-an-express-app) for helpers files. Learn step by step.. :D happy coding.

Comment: Unfortunately votes are anonymous. Whoever marked down-vote mention the reason please, it helps others as well as to make SO community more better by removing "Poorly written posts".. constructive comments are always welcome, but without comments its just annoying ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this,
in your index.js

```
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
... what ever you want
});
module.exports = router;
```

and in your app.js

```
var route = require('./routes/index.js');
app.use('', route);
```

i hope this helps

Comment: You're correct that he's not using the controller, but you're path to the controller doesn't match his file structure.  Also note my comment to the OP, you can use it to make your answer more complete

Comment: Router is said to be deprecated in the console when I am using it. Any idea ?

Comment: oups! i forget to add module.exports = router; at the end of index.js can you try it like that